# canvasengine limiting elements display inside an element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frameworks, canvasengine

I am trying to display some element wrapped up inside another element, and just display a certain part of them (limited in a rect)

I tried to use `.clip()` on the parent element, but then i got a lot of strange results : like if I change the parent `x` and `y`, let say I put `parent.y = 20`, then for some reason, the children inside the `.clip()` will be displayed like they also had `y = 20` beside the fact they're `y = 0` ;  so in the end, children double the `y` of their parent (20 from the origin like their parent and then for some reason another 20 inside the parent)

What I don't understand is if I inspect a child, its `y` is 0 and its `real_Y` is 20, but on my screen it is obviously 40

When I remove `.clip()` from the parent, everything works properly but I need to crop the display of the children in a rect

So is it some kind of bug, or maybe I am doing something wrong, or maybe there is another way to do what i want beside the `.clip()`

example images of the issue

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/613587x0y0.jpg]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/613587x0y0.jpg))</sub>

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/555325x0y20.jpg]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/555325x0y20.jpg))</sub>

There is also another "bug" way more annoying, when i am using a radius to a child, it simply breaks the .clip() of the parent

Code should be something like that (in ready):

```
el1 = this.createElement();
el2 = this.createElement();

el1.rect(0, 0, 376, 212);
el1.clip();

el2.drawImage('slot');
el2.x = 200;

el1.append(el2);
stage.append(el1);
```

with this I have the first picture, if I add `el1.y = 20` I have the second picture, so I would have to add `el2.y = -20` to get what I really want

Comment: Please consider showing us the code you're using.